# Spring Securiy: Allow admin to do everything

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

How do I allow admin (user with role ROLE_ADMIN) to access everything without explicitly mentioning him in every expression? Currently I have my controller's methods annotated as

```
@PreAuthorize("(hasRole('ROLE_VENDOR') and hasPermission(#product, 'admin')) or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

but I want to have it simple like this while allowing admin to do anything:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_VENDOR') and hasPermission(#product, 'admin')")
```

Is it possible? How do I do that? Important to note that hasPermission(#product, ...) is evaluated to false for admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use hierarchical role.

Here is a typical configuration:

```
<bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
    <constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
</bean>
<bean id="roleHierarchy"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <property name="hierarchy">
        <value>
            ROLE_ADMIN > ROLE_STAFF
            ROLE_STAFF > ROLE_USER
            ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

[reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/authz-arch.html)

**Edit**

You probably also need to write a custom [PermissionEvaluator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/PermissionEvaluator.html). If you don't already have one: just extends [AclPermissionEvaluator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/acls/AclPermissionEvaluator.html) and overwrite only `hasPermission` to return true as soon as the user have the `admin` role; otherwise return `super.hasPermission(...)`

Configure your beans like this:

```
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled">
     <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler" />
</security:global-method-security>

<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
   <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="customPermissionEvaluator" />
   ... 
</bean>
```

Comment: @igo I just added a suggestion for the 'hasPermission' problem

Answer (score 1):

Grant administrators all the necessary roles or use hierarchical roles as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#authz-hierarchical-roles).

Comment: I dont want to grant him all roles, that would be a lot of work and it doesn't solve the problem. Currently I am using hierarchies but problem is that hasPermission is false for admin (because of some business logic behind it; I updated question to note this).

Comment: Maybe extending AclPermissionEvaluator to check for admin role would be the way to go then. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/acls/AclPermissionEvaluator.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this in security-config

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    // your security patterns
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('admin')" />

</http>
```

If you put this pattern at the end of the list, after checking all rules and not matchning any pattern at the end spring will allow `admin` send request on any address which equals any controller in practice

Comment: That won't help with method level security.

Comment: @Jukka why not? if you wont add any `@Preauthorize` to only-for-admin-methods it should work

Comment: @smajlo, read the question, his methods ARE being called by users of other roles as well.